# IF-statement based on overlap

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, range, overlap

I am trying to create a simple function in python 3.7 that returns whether or not a specific amplifier is under export compliance or not.
The criteria depend on saturated power, frequency range, and fractional bandwidth.

As you can see from the example below, the compliance threshold is decreasing with increasing frequency, which makes it simple just to look for the frequency endpoint. Except for the condition at 31.8-37GHz.

Can anyone suggest a change to my code such that any frequency range that overlaps the criteria, will get flagged?

```
def amplifier():
    freq_start = float(input('Start frequency in GHz: '))
    freq_stop = float(input('Stop frequency in Ghz: '))
    psat = float(input('Saturated power in dBm: '))
    fractional_bw = (freq_stop-freq_start)/((freq_start+freq_stop)/2)

    if 16 < freq_stop <= 31.8 and fractional_bw > 0.10 and psat > 34.77:
        return 'Export compliance according to 3A001.b.2.c'

    if 31.8 < freq_stop <= 37 and psat > -70:
        return 'Export compliance according to 3A001.b.2.d'

    if 37 < freq_stop <= 43.5 and fractional_bw > 0.10 and psat > 30:
        return 'Export compliance according to 3A001.b.2.e'

    if 43.5 < freq_stop <= 75 and fractional_bw > 0.10 and psat > 15:
        return 'Export compliance according to 3A001.b.2.f'

    if 75 < freq_stop <= 90 and fractional_bw > 0.05 and psat > 10:
        return 'Export compliance according to 3A001.b.2.g'

    if 90 < freq_stop and psat > -70:
        return 'Export compliance according to 3A001.b.2.h'

    else:
        return 'Not export compliance according to 3A001.b.2'
```

Comment: There is no overlapping frequency range in your sample code. Do you mean that `psat > -70` may overlap with the others, or that ``fractional_bw`` and thus ``freq_start`` are not checked? If so, please specify the criteria more clearly.

Comment: Note that returning strings is a bad idea for anything not directly handled by humans. Parsing strings to figure out what a function result is is extremely fragile. You should consider just returning the appropriate specification (e.g. "3A001.b.2.h") and raise an Exception if the input is non-compliant.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, sorry for not making it so clear. For example, if the amplifier has a working frequency of 30 to 40GHz and `psat` is 20dBm. In this case it will not be flagged by criterion 2 or 3, although it is breaking my criteria 2. How do I write a condition, such that any overlap within the range 31.8GHz to 37GHz with `psat` higher than -70dBm will activate the statement? By the way the output string is meant to be read by humans.

Comment: Please clarify. Your criteria are made to accept, not reject, amplifiers ("reject by default"). Using 30GHz-40GHz @20dBm is correctly flagged as breaking all your criteria, and reported as non-compliant. Do you mean that satisfying *either* frequency range or power is sufficient? Do you mean that your ``freq_stop`` check signifies the minimum range, so any range *greater* than (31.8, 37) is valid?

Comment: I mean to say that 30GHz-40GHz @20dBm should be flagged as fulfilling criteria 2, because within the range 30-40 are values that fulfill 31.8-37 and 20>-70. 
The phrase 'export compliance' means we have to apply for a permit. Sorry for my bad english and reverse logic.

Comment: So you do actually want to test whether the frequency range is *larger* than the standards' range, or overlaps? E.g. do you want ``freq_start <= 37 and 31.8 < freq_stop`` or ``freq_start <= 37 or 31.8 < freq_stop``?